# Media resource could not be decoded

Tags: amazon-s3, jwplayer

I am converting avi videos to mp4 and uploading to amazon s3. I am proving the video url to jw player and it is showing the following error

[Media resource](https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/F14B72D5-A6AA-91BE-1C36-1E97309786C0.mp4)  could not be decoded

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Using the S3 console, make sure the video is being provided with the correct MIME type of video/mp4. Amazonaws always gets this wrong, and uses a MIME type of something like application/octet-stream.

Comment: Also, provide a link, so we can confirm the issue.

Comment: @MisterNeutron: Yes, they are giving the correct MIME type i.e video/mp4

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer: please find the link as https://ppe.maventus.com/player.php?v=655

Comment: You're using a <video> tag to embed the video. That's not the way JW Player works. You also don't need the "modes" parameters at all. Please see this simple example: http://misterneutron.com/JW6video/

Comment: Now I have found the reason why it was showing error Media resource could not be decoded, it is because while I was doing the video format conversion to mp4, it was not using the libx264 codec. 

Note: If it is showing any error while converting format using libx264, then install libavcodec-extra-53 in libav library, then it will work.

Thanks all for your valuable answers, cheers :)